# Get a string from a c++ library with a java wrapper around it

Tags: java, c#, c++, xamarin

Good Evening,

I have a c++ library file where I am trying to get a string value from but not by return.

This is for an Android Application build in Xamarin.

.cpp file

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_MyNamespace_ClassName_FunctionName
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring returnString)
    {
            returnString = env->NewStringUTF("returnStringValue");
            return 1;
        }
```

In my Solution I have:

.cs File

```
namespace myNamespace
    {
        [DllImport("FolderName", EntryPoint = "Java_MyNamespace_ClassName_FunctionName")]
                private static extern int FunctionName(IntPtr env, IntPtr thiz, IntPtr returnString);

        void test_function()
        {
            IntPtr j = new IntPtr();

            int status = FunctionName(JNIEnv.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, j);

            string ss = j.ToString();
            //Where I am expecting ss to be containing "returnStringValue".
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are allocating a `Java.Lang.String` (`java::lang::String`) in C++ thus you can not marshal/convert it via a C# String IntPtr directly. The `IntPtr` will be a handle to an `Java.Lang.Object` so get the `Java.Lang.String` from that and than you can get a .Net `String` if needed..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SushiHangover

We created a byte array

```
byte[] x = new byte[120];
```

Allocated that memory and copied it

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy()
```

And then converted using:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()
```

Apparently this worked verry well.

Regards